# How to scheduling the download of pdf from clicking a button in webpage with Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to automate the download of a pdf recipe from a webpage that contains a list of pdfs. Every pdf could be downloaded by clicking a button, and every month the system upgrades the first item-button of the list with the last recipe.

I'm trying to understand how to create a Python's script that automates (every month) the download of the pdf by clicking the first button of the item list.
It would be perfect if I transpose the pdf into a csv file and write it into a DB MYsql.

Does anyone suggest which are the steps? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look into:

- Using cron jobs if you need the script to run monthly
- Parsing a website (as in the HTML) and taking the relevant elements that you need from it
- Downloading files via HTTP using python